# Obter nome das planilhas que contem em um arquivo excel com c#

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Estou com um problema referente a obter o nome das planilhas que tem que em um arquivo do Excel. Preciso ler um arquivo que contem varias planilhas, e gostaria de obter o nome de todas e listar em um `ComboBox`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo: Neste caso precisaria de um método que lesse o arquivo Excel, e retornasse ao usuário em um ComboBox com esses 3 itens (*FINANCEIRO*, *CONTAS* E *PRODUTOS*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse [**artigo**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8096/C-Retrieve-Excel-Workbook-Sheet-Names) tem um exemplo que demonstra isso utilizando o [OLEDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx). A função retorna uma *array* contendo os nomes das folhas, no parâmetro `excelFile` você apontará para o arquivo Excel.

```c-sharp
// Utilize o namespace  System.Data.OleDb;
private String[] GetExcelSheetNames(string excelFile)
{
  OleDbConnection objConn = null;
  System.Data.DataTable dt = null;

  try
  {
    // Configura a Connection String
    String connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1\";", excelFile);

    // Cria o objeto de conexão usando a connection string
    objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

    // Abre a conexão com o banco de dados
    objConn.Open();
    dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

    if(dt == null)
    {
      return null;
    }

    String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
    int i = 0;

    // Adiciona os nomes na array
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
      excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
      i++;
    }

    // Loop através de todas as folhas se você quiser também..
    for(int j=0; j < excelSheets.Length; j++)
    {
      // Consultar cada folha de excel
    }

    return excelSheets;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    return null;
  }
  finally
  {
    if(objConn != null)
    {
      objConn.Close();
      objConn.Dispose();
    }
    if(dt != null)
    {
      dt.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

**Nota**: Caso você esteja utilizando o **Excel 2003** altere a *string* de conexão para:

```
string connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\";", excelFile);
```